# How to wait after a FormRequest?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a website in which i need to submit a form and wait for data to load through javascript. I am using `FormRequest.form_reponse()` function but it call its callback function without waiting for data to load is there any way to wait for some time until data is loaded.

````
  return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'District': '01',
            'AccountIdentifier':'002345'},
            callback=self.fatchdata)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy doesn't support JS rendering. You should use Splash or Chrome to handle JS data.

The better option though is to check requests at Chrome Dev Tools network tab and forge the desired request manually.